# Creating calculated columns based on where

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create calculated fields for a workflow that I will export to an excel pivot table.  I am doing this by creating a view and selecting columns from another table while creating extra necessary columns.

I am faced with the task of populating rows within a column based on a calculation only when rows of another column equal a certain value.  I have tried different variations of the below formula to no avail.

```
CREAT MATERIALIZED VIEW adwords_calculated AS
SELECT SUM("Impressions" * 1 ) WHERE AD Relevance = 
"Positive Ad Relevance" AS Positive Ad Impressions
```

Please let me know if anything within this formula is unclear.

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN AD Relevance = 
"Positive Ad Relevance" THEN Impressions" * 1 END)` or `SUM("Impressions" * 1) FILTER (WHERE AD Relevance = 
"Positive Ad Relevance")`